# error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout current topology: Type: Single Servers

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I need to import a CSV file to mongoDB unfortunately i'm having below error:

```
    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
    current topology: Type: Single
    Servers:
    Addr: eaderline:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp: lookup eaderline: no such host
```

my import string looks like that:

```
mongoimport --host Test-shard-0/test-shard-00-00-gceee.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-gceee.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-gceee.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db EngineeringProject --collection FirstName --type csv -file "C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\INFA\ProjektInzynierski\DaneDBzMC\imiona.csv" -headerline
```

The funny part about this error is that, i was able to import data to mongodb a 2 weeks ago by similar string which looks like this one below, and today it's imposible, why?

```
mongoimport --host Test-shard-0/test-shard-00-00-gceee.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-gceee.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-gceee.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db Test2 --collection COL_First --type csv -file "C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\Przykladowy\Mapy\liczba.csv" -headerline
```

Does anyone see any mistake?

I have checked the port 27017 on my machine is free, maybe there is something going on on the cluster side?
Is there a way to launch an empty import, just for checking the connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use URI command It works for me in windows command line

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb://**user:passwd**@***host:port***/database?ssl=true&replicaSet=**replicasetneme**"
-c **collection** --file **csvFile** --fields **fields with comma separated**
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I was able to import my CSV file via mongodb GUI client, Compass.

In the meantime i bumped into another issue. Compass connect do the cluster showed the DBs, but didn't show the collections. It turned out that my user had a bad role. I deleted the user and add it once again, and it worked, I could see the collections also.

After that I was able to import my CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

1.First make sure that db port 27017 is not used by  other local server instance

2.If using cloud, then log in to console and Click on `Cluster Name` then `Command Line Tools` copy the mongo import command which will look some thing like

```
mongoimport --host DemoCluster-shard-0/democluster-shard-00-00-5zjhn.mongodb.net:27017,democluster-shard-00-01-5zjhn.mongodb.net:27017,democluster-shard-00-02-5zjhn.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username <USERNAME>--password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --file <FILENAME>
```

Note: Pass TYPE as `--jsonArray` if file contains json aray

Answer (score 0):

Every time I face this type of error:

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server...
```

It's because MongoDB didn't start.
Try to start it manually.
As a windows user:
[image: Mongodb error connecting to host]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the `--ssl` option. It did not matter if I was passing it or not in the connection string, it needed to be passed as a parameter. The following command worked.

```bash
mongorestore --noIndexRestore --ssl --db database --verbose --uri mongodb://user:password==@host.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?retrywrites=false --archive < documents.dump
```

This one did not

```
mongorestore --noIndexRestore --db database --verbose --uri mongodb://user:password==@host.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?retrywrites=false&ssl=true --archive < documents.dump
```

The same issue is also for `mongoimport`