# mongoimport - server selection timeout

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to import a csv into my mongo database but when I run the following command:

```
mongoimport --type csv -d casinos -c casinos --headerline --drop total_cleaned_up.csv
```

I get the following:

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server 
selection timeout
current topology: Type: Single
Servers:
Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: 
connection(localhost:27017[-121]) connection is closed
```

I have mongod running in the background, and I know for sure my server is connected to the database. When I use postman to create dummy data, it works just fine. My mongoose schema is in the same filepath as my csv. I'm not sure if this is a firewall issue, or something else. The closest answer I can find is from this stackoverflow post, but it doesnt seem to be working for me (its quite verbose, so I very well might be typing it wrong as well)

[error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout current topology: Type: Single Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413297/error-connecting-to-host-could-not-connect-to-server-server-selection-error-s)

any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: What do you get from running `traceroute -T -p 27017 127.0.0.1`? You are doing this command on the same machine correct?

Comment: @EternalHour Version 1.4a12+Darwin
Usage: traceroute [-adDeFInrSvx] [-A as_server] [-f first_ttl] [-g gateway] [-i iface]
 [-M first_ttl] [-m max_ttl] [-p port] [-P proto] [-q nqueries] [-s src_addr]
 [-t tos] [-w waittime] [-z pausemsecs] host [packetlen]

Comment: @EternalHour when you say am I doing this command from the same machine, what do you mean exactly

Comment: Looks like your OS doesn't support that command. I mean that you are trying to import the csv on the same machine that has the db running on it. What about `telnet 127.0.0.1 27017`?

Comment: @EternalHour - I get a command not found for this. and yes - I am running it on the same machine